# Главный поток в Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

Существует такой код (упрощенный):

```
public void f()
{
    for(int i=0;i<1000000000;i++)
    {
        DrawTexture(x_, y_, id);// очень тяжелая операция
        textGameObject.text = i.ToString();
    }
}
```

Запускаю всё в главном потоке.

Почему у меня приложение зависает на n-ое кол секунд, а потом показывает в `textGameObject.text` последнее значение? Разве это все не должно выполняться поэтапно? Тяжелая операция, вывод, тяжелая операция, вывод и т.д?

Comment: не должна. почему вы решили, что должна?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Выполняться поэтапно не должно. Выполнение метода произойдет до конца (все 1000000000 итераций), а только затем будет выполняться следующий метод (лю) Ваш пример аналогичен ситуации, если вы наберете похожий код вне Unity3d на любом другом языке программирования. А что касается изменения текста в вашем `textGameObject.text`, то чтобы это происходило поэтапно, нужно разбивать *по кадрам*, а не итерациям цикла. При выполнении подобного кода в Unity3d в виде обычного метода (не сопрограммы) все итерации вашего цикла произойдут за 1 кадр, то есть unity не будет ничего перерисовывать пока не разберется с выполнением вашего кода. Если хотите реализовать этот код "поэтапно" смотрите в сторону сопрограмм, они же [Coroutines](https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/530/Manual/Coroutines.html).